# Solution of a functional equation with cosine transform

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

What are the functions verifying:

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(t) \cos(2\pi xt)=\lambda \frac{1}{x} f(\frac{1}{x})$$

With $\lambda$ a constant ?
(Functions $x^{-\alpha}$ with $0<\alpha<1$ are solutions but can we find other solutions?)

Comment: Well, it is still not quite integrable... In any case, the equation is linear in $f$, so any linear combination of solutions also does the job. In fact, $\alpha$ can be complex, and `linear combinations' can be replaced by integrals. This brings us to the [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform). In general one can expect that the solution can be found by taking the Mellin transform of both sides; when I have more time, I will try to write down the details.

Comment: Some more thoughts: After (formally) taking the Mellin transform of both sides, the equation takes form $(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)\cos(\pi s/2)\mathcal{M}f(1-s)=\lambda \mathcal{M}f(1-s)$, which is ill-posed and suggests that the only solutions are linear combinations of $x^{s-1}$, where $s$ is a (complex) solution of the equation $(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)\cos(\pi s/2)=\lambda \mathcal{M}f(1-s)$. There is an infinite family of solutions; when $\lambda=\tfrac{1}{2}$, infinitely many of them seem to lie on $\operatorname{Re}s=\tfrac{1}{2}$, and in general they appear to concentrate around this line.